# Convert English to logic

Tags: predicate-logic

How to write the following sentence using propositional logic:

Only monkeys properly appreciate the value of art.

Is this good:

Let $M(x)$ be '$x$ is a monkey' and $A(x)$ be '$x$ properly appreciates the value of art', where the domain of $x$ is the set of all animals.

In this case, $\forall x\ A(x) \rightarrow M(x)$ or $\forall x\ A(x) \iff M(x)$?

Comment: If only monkeys appreciate art, then if you are not a monkey then you don't appreciate art. For all x not an element of monkey implies x is not an art lover. That should be pretty easy to translate into propositional logic.

Comment: Your second answer, $\forall x\ A(x) \iff M(x)$, is too strong. It might be translated to "*All and* only monkeys properly appreciate the value of art".

Comment: Yes, if my answer wasn't clear enough I apologize--the correct form is $(\forall x)(A(x)\to M(x))$; like @joeA pointed out, the second answer is too strong.

Answer (score 1):

You seem right, but you may want to formulate it as follows to reflect the nature of the question: If $x$ properly appreciates art, then $x$ is a monkey AND if $x$ is not a monkey, then $x$ does not appreciate art, but this latter statement is just the contrapositive of the previous statement which takes the form $(\forall x)(A(x)\to M(x))$. Thus, I do not see any issue with your formulation.